# Selenium click on link

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium's IDE in FireFox to do some testing, and I want Selenium to click the second link (Text2). Any idea how I do that? Unfortunately I don't have access to the HTML and can't modify it. The record function doesn't seem to register the click.

The code is attached below. Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <span class="class3"><a href="#" onclick="fn1();">Text1</a></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
        <span class="class3"><a href="#" onclick="fn2();">Text2</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have Text1 twice in your example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium supports the `link=Link Text` locator as well. If you know the exact link text, you can use this locator, but not otherwise. So for your examples above: `link=text2` or `link=View Previous Statements`. (See [this site](http://marakana.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators.html) and [this site](http://www.lawrencesong.com/blog/selenium-element-locators) for other locators.)

Comment: @Roddy - in that Link Text what should be given? 

<a title="Logout" href="/base/base/base.en">

So i should give logout in Link Text?

Comment: @EmmanuelAngelo.R Let's say you have `<a href="/logout">Click to Logout</a>`. Then your link text is `Click to Logout`.

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try

```
//a[contains(text(),'text2')]     OR  //span/a[contains(text(),'text2')]
```

Looking for same or anything else?

Comment: It didn't work - I'm afraid I'm woefully unfamiliar with Xpath. What exactly is that doing?

Comment: it will find text2 in tag a, and you can click on that text then.

Comment: [error] locator not found: //a[contains(text(),'View Previous Statements')]
Where View Previous Statements = text2

Comment: //a[contains(text(),'View Previous Statements']  try this 1

Comment: Same error, unfortunately. :(
[error] locator not found: //a[contains(text(),'View Previous Statements']

Comment: can you please share HTML? For that text only

Comment: It's in the question, but here:

<div class="class1">
   <div class="class2"><span class="class3"><a href="#" onclick="fn1();">View Previous Statements</a></span></div>
  </div>

Comment: It wasn't working either - but I got the answer from Roddy above. Thank you so much though! I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please disregard this post. Selenium is ignoring the "Value" field and simply selecting the 1st occurrence of span.class3.
Sorry about this. I should have tested more before posting.

Original post:
*I have a similar webpage, and I was able to use the following Selenium IDE command:
    command: clickAndWait
    target:  css=span.class3
    value:   Text1*