# Selenium ide :How to click on a link

Tags: css, selenium-ide

I need your help  to  do an action with selenium ide.
 I want to click on 2nd  link

```
<a class="more_button" href="http://example.com/view/9680-action1.html">Do action </a>

<a class="more_button" href="http://example.com/view/9680-action2.html">Do action </a>

<a class="more_button" href="http://example.com/view/9680-action3.html">Do action </a>
```

I want to open action 2 using   this text as matching text :*action2.html*

I tried with  css `a.more_button:contains("action2.html")`
but I don't know how to edit it .

Comment: read this. It may help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311100/selenium-click-on-link

Comment: Thanks,
solved with this
//a[contains(@href,'action2')]

Answer (score -1):

Using xpath, click on second link:

```
click | //a[@href='http://example.com/view/9680-action2.html']
```

Comment: i have no idea how link is wrote(ahead is just an example) but i know it contain "action2"