# Web scraping with Selenium - clicking on link with javascript (can't find element)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I've gotten selenium to work perfectly but am wondering how I would go about clicking on the link of the string I've entered:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  

url = "http://www.howlongtobeat.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

search_element = driver.find_element_by_name("global_search_box")
search_element.clear()
search_element.send_keys("God of War (2018)")
search_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div id=[@class='nav_playthroughs_load]")
link.click()
```

how would I get it to click on the link entitled "God of War (2018)"

I'm getting this error:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0343b11486bd> in <module>()
----> 1 search_element = driver.find_element_by_name("global_search_box")
      2 search_element.clear()
      3 search_element.send_keys("God of War (2018)")
      4 search_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
      5 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element_by_name(self, name)
    485             element = driver.find_element_by_name('foo')
    486         """
--> 487         return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
    488 
    489     def find_elements_by_name(self, name):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    953         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    954             'using': by,
--> 955             'value': value})['value']
    956 
    957     def find_elements(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    310         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    311         if response:
--> 312             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    313             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    314                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.79)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64)
```

thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium click on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311100/selenium-click-on-link)

Comment: that post doesn't really help I think I'm having a problem locating the correct html

Comment: What is the difference between your this post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892591/cant-find-the-element-i-need-in-javascript-with-selenium-to-click-on-link/50894361#50894361) one?

Comment: @demouser123 it's basicly the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't find the element I need in Javascript with selenium to click on link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892591/cant-find-the-element-i-need-in-javascript-with-selenium-to-click-on-link)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the link with text as **God of War (2018)** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *LINK-TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "God of War (2018)"))).click()
  ```
- *CSS-SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.text_blue[title^='God of War']"))).click()
  ```
- *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='text_blue'][@title=\"God of War (2018)\"]"))).click()
  ```