# can't find the element I need in Javascript with selenium to click on link

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, element

I can't find the element I need to tell selenium that I want it to click it, I believe it is because the page is generated by javascript

can someone please help? maybe show me a way to do it and then explain how to find?

the website I'm working on is www.howlongtobeat.com

I want selenium to do the following:

go to http://www.howlongtobeat.com => click on the search tab => enter "God of War (2018)" => click the link that pops up

this is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.howlongtobeat.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

search_element = driver.find_element_by_name("global_search_box")
search_element.clear()
search_element.send_keys("God of War (2018)")
search_element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


#this is where my isssue is, I dont know what element it is or how to find
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("input")
link.click()
```

it's just the last step I need help with

can someone advise?

Comment: where you want to click ?/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ankur Singh solution works fine. You can also use the CSS Selector to do the same clicking (I generally prefer CSS Selectors)

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h3.shadow_text")))
element1= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h3.shadow_text > a')
element1.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to click on link:-

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "search_list_image"))
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("God of War (2018)")
link.click()
```